# how do I get a client's IP address in php (help! nothing works!)

Tags: php, ip-address

I've been trying to fetch the client IP for a php tool that I created, but it will only get one IP address, no matter who uses it. I'm using repl.it, and it probably is getting the server IP.

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$_SESSION['ipAddr'] = $ip;
```

Comment: Looks like repl.it masks the user's IP or uses a proxy, so it can't be done. https://replit.com/talk/ask/How-to-get-IP-address-of-user/147452 https://replit.com/talk/share/Problem-trying-to-get-user-ip/15713 https://replit.com/talk/ask/How-do-I-obtain-the-IP-address-of-a-user-in-Flask/136670

Comment: You could use [the browser's developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and check which headers you're receiving. Most proxies put the original remote IP in a header. You can then get this header from the [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server) superglobal. Basically what you're already trying to do, but you might no be using the correct header name.

Comment: Hm. How else can I provide an unique identifier code for a specific device?

Comment: You're asking a different question now, so it's better to ask a new question. It's a pity you didn't do anything with my comment. You might have a [X-Real-IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72615121/how-is-html-header-x-real-ip-created) header, or an other variant. It's worth checking out. Just doing `echo print_r($_SERVER);` gives you all the headers.